# Node.js server file execution

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node and am trying to understand how it all works. I have a server.js file which configures and starts up a node server. My question is, does this code only get executed once or does it get executed once for each new user. Say for example I added the line:

```
console.log("test");
```

to the file. Would this line be executed only once or would it be executed each time a new user accesses the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing just console.log() on its own will only run once. Commands that repeat for every user must be written in the context of a `get` or other server starting hook.

For example, this sample code will print foo just once, but test for each user:

```
console.log('foo')
//
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('test')
})
```

Comment: in this case, the function passed to `http.createServer` will be executed by node every time a request hits the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have not really provided enough information to answer your question.  If your are using the standard server example app and added the console.log statement in a request handler, it would be executed each time that code block handled a request.  If placed in the code block that starts the server, it would only be executed when the server starts. Does that make sense?